# What is 'Carry-forward verification' defense against MITM?

Tags: authentication, key-exchange, man-in-the-middle

Wikipedia article on [Man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack#Defenses_against_the_attack) mentions, in the list of defenses against it, some method called "*Carry-forward verification*", but it does not explain it. I am curious about different MITM defense methods in general. Can someone describe this method or point to description? (Of course googling does not give anything except wikipedia itself with its clones.)

ps. Would be grateful also if someone points me to more elaborated survey of MITM defense methods (and especially for key exchange).

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#What_Is_Pinning.3F

Comment: Since you're interested in MITM in general [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/thesis.pdf) should be useful

Answer (score 4):

That was a bad edit to Wikipedia.  The phrase `Carry-forward verification` is not a standard, well-known term in the cryptographic literature.  It should not have been included in Wikipedia without a reference to something more specific.  But oh well, no one is perfect, sometimes these things happen.

Your request for an elaborate survey of MITM defense is most likely too broad for this site; the kind of defenses that are suitable are dependent upon the specific application domain.  You can read up about certificate authorities, web of trust, X.509, certificate pinning, trust-on-first-use (aka key continuity), and many other models.  There's *lots* written on this topic.